# Replace or Remove special characters such as ' and " in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

In the data frame that I am working on, there are several columns that contain special characters such as " and ' .
They are either at the end or in the beginning of the column name.

How can I get rid of them?
Is there any chance to read files with these characters?

I have tried several options, however, it did not work.

Examples of the columns are following:

```
est_soilty_Gh''

upd_siffer_Kh'g

est_soilty_M'''
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Those aren't special characters. You can replace them using `str.replace` or `str.strip("'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
df.column_name = df.column_name.str.replace(r'["\']', '')
```

##### Edit:

Use regex, thanks to @[mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)

Comment: Don't replace twice, use a regex `r'["\']'`

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting better, I didn't use list comprehension that time at least.

Comment: Huge thanks for the quick help. It worked! Completely forgot about the escape character!

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"est_soilty_Gh''": [1,2,4],
                    "upd_siffer_Kh'g": [0,0.2,0.5],
                    "est_soilty_M'''": [2,3,4]})



    est_soilty_Gh''  upd_siffer_Kh'g  est_soilty_M'''
0                1              0.0                2
1                2              0.2                3
2                4              0.5                4
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"'", '')


print(df)

est_soilty_Gh  upd_siffer_Khg  est_soilty_M
0              1             0.0             2
1              2             0.2             3
2              4             0.5             4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked as well.  When there is '  , it works fine. As to "   , I think I would need to use escape character